# Batch File If Statements

Tags: batch-file

New to batch file creation, familiar with c++ coding, and having trouble with if's

My statement here is simply attempting to take an string input and run it through an if like a password, but I always get 'Incorrect' leading me to believe there might be a problem with what the If statement is checking.

(And yes, I know its Case Sensitive)

```
echo Input to continue the patching process
set input=
set /p= 
if "%input%"=="Bookkeeper" (
    echo Correct
) else (
    echo Incorrect
)
```

Comment: Where would the value of `input` change?

Comment: You were very close. The syntax for getting user input is `set /p variable=prompt`. Change your third line to `set /p input=`.

Comment: @SomethingDark Thanks alot man. I only had google and shady sites to go off of so i thought the way i was prompting was the correct way

Comment: Stick to https://ss64.com/nt/ for the basics, and you can always go into the command prompt and follow any command with a `/?` for an explanation of how to use it.

Comment: Note: the following will make the comparison case insensitive: if /I "%input%"=="Bookkeeper"

Comment: @SomethingDark - You might want to propose that as an answer, not just as a comment - and then the querent (Adobe Wall Hacks) should accept it - this will show that the issue has been addressed satisfactorily (and gets Something Dark a few rep points).

Comment: I considered it, but it would be hypocritical, since I voted to close as "caused by a typo."

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct method to do what you want.

```
set /p input=Enter your answer:

if /i "%input%" == "Bookkeeper" (
    echo Correct
) else (
    echo Incorrect
)
```

Notes:

- Please review the `set /p` statement's syntax carefully

  - `set /p` without a variable name is *usually* used to print without CR\LF
  - the part after `=`, is the prompt(i.e. this replaces the `echo` part)
- `/i` flag in an `if` statement tells it to compare case-insensitive

  - I've added spaces between the two compared item, but that doesn't change anything.